# Registered URL not found

Tags: flask

We had implemented a two-in-one backend with Flask. For the website itself (which we call it `tekid`), we're having no trouble. But for the management portal (which we call it `tekid-admin`), even though using the same view registries, the WSGI server (both dev and prod) returns **404 NOT FOUND** for all requests.

#### Related Codes

The CLI entries are registered as

- `tekid` -> `tekid.cli.www:cli`
- `tekid-admin` -> `tekid.cli.adm:cli`

Following is the code we used to hold Flask application object:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Module entrypoint of TekID website."""

# in `tekid/app/www.py` for `tekid`
from tekid.urls.www import app
# in `tekid/app/adm.py` for `tekid-admin`
from tekid.urls.adm import app
```

Following is the code we used for CLI entry:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""CLI for TekID website."""

import click
import flask

import tekid.core.typing as typing
# in `tekid/cli/www.py` for `tekid`
from tekid.app.www import app
# in `tekid/cli/adm.py` for `tekid-admin`
from tekid.app.adm import app

__all__ = ['cli']


@click.group(cls=flask.cli.FlaskGroup, create_app=lambda: app)
def cli() -> typing.NoneType:
    """Management script for the TekID website."""
```

Following is the code we used for routing registry (we're using a centralised registering mechanism as proposed by Flask itself):

```py
# tekid/urls/www.py & tekid/urls/adm.py (same when testing)
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""URL routing for TekID website."""
# pylint: disable=wrong-import-position

from tekid.core.macro import FLASK as app

__all__ = ['app']

###############################################################################
# load HTML pages

from tekid.urls.pages import *  # pylint: disable=unused-wildcard-import

# index.html
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=load_index)
... # same routing registry codes
```

#### Expected Behavior

**NB: `tekid` and `tekid-admin` should give the same output**

The `routes` command would give like this:

```
$ tekid routes
# or
$ tekid-admin routes
Endpoint        Methods            Rule
--------------  -----------------  -----------------------------------
load_contact    GET, POST          /contact/
load_expertise  GET                /expertise/
load_index      GET                /
load_news       GET, POST          /news/
...
static          GET                /static/<path:filename>
```

We try `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/` after `run` on the website (`tekid`):

```
$ tekid run
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 332-955-135
/fakepath/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py:220: UserWarning: The session cookie domain is an IP address. This may not work as intended in some browsers. Add an entry to your hosts file, for example "localhost.localdomain", and use that instead.
  "The session cookie domain is an IP address. This may not work"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Nov/2019 17:20:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
<!--
  _______   _    _____ _____    _     _      _
 |__   __| | |  |_   _|  __ \  | |   | |    | |
    | | ___| | __ | | | |  | | | |   | |_ __| |
    | |/ _ \ |/ / | | | |  | | | |   | __/ _` |
    | |  __/   < _| |_| |__| | | |___| || (_| |_
    |_|\___|_|\_\_____|_____/  |______\__\__,_(_)
-->
... (the actual HTML page)
```

#### Actual Behavior

With the same configs as above, we try `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/` after `run` on the management portal (`tekid-admin`):

```
$ tekid-admin run
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: ***-***-***
/fakepath/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py:220: UserWarning: The session cookie domain is an IP address. This may not work as intended in some browsers. Add an entry to your hosts file, for example "localhost.localdomain", and use that instead.
  "The session cookie domain is an IP address. This may not work"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Nov/2019 17:06:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

#### Environment

- Python version: 3.7.4
- Flask version: 1.1.1
- Werkzeug version: 0.16.0

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try taking the warning's advice and run `curl 
 http://localhost:5000/` ?

Comment: Showing the relevant parts `tekid-admin` (e.g., where you're setting up the route) would help.

Comment: @Jamie_D yes, and it's all the same results

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Okay, the related codes had been added.

Comment: In your position, I'd put a `sys.exit(0)` right before `@app.route('/')` to verify that it's actually getting reached in both cases. Then I'd double-check that `app` isn't getting overwritten with a second instance after you register the route.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith aye, in the CLI declaration function's `create_app` argument, I wrapped the `lambda` function and printed `app.url_map` to see if the URLs are correctly registered, and voila, both `tekid` and `tekid-admin` have the same URL registry while the issue remained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically from the Flask and/or Werkzeug documentation (which I could not recall the original source), Flask can only recognise the imported application instance from no more than *2* (?) layers recursively.

That is to say, the application failed to identify which one was the actual instance to be used and rather make an empty instance without any registered URLs.

The solution was to simply reconstruct the code and just import the application instance in each file and do the same thing to import the URL registries in the CLI files as for tekid/urls/www.py & tekid/urls/adm.py.